# How do I represent and update the order of docments in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, database-design

I'm building a file manager for my web app, I need a user to be able to manually reorder files. How do I represent and update the order of files in database?

I want to create a list of files that a user can manually reorder with drag and drop, so a file can be inserted into any position between any two files. I'm trying to find a way to store and update positions of all files.

Reordering an array or json object would be easy, but the problem is that each file is it's own object in the database. I can't just add a `position` field to every file, because if a user drops a file in the middle of the list, I'd have to update poitions of all the files after that point.

What are some ways to represent and update the position of each file, so that they could be sorted in custom order?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

## Option 1 - Position Field

Using the position field, instead of incrementing by 1, increment by a larger number e.g. 1000.  Whenever you add a new item, look at the position at the item before and after, find the half-way point between their positions and use that for the new item.  e.g. inserting between position 1000 and 2000 would be 1500.

What this does is allows you to minimize the number of times you have to update everything that comes after this item.

Back in the days of BASIC (with line numbers), this is how we avoided having to renumber our code whenever we had to go back and insert code.  Not the prettiest solution, but it does work.

## Option 2 - Linked List

Store a link to the next item. When you insert into the middle, you just need to update the records for the previous item. You'll also need to update the previous item in the case of deletes.